# How do I prevent the Mac from sleeping while on display sleep on battery power?

Tags: mac, battery, sleep-wake, power

[image]

So while on battery power you have the option to prevent the computer from sleeping when display is off. How ever this option is only available while on power adapter. Is there a way to do this on battery power? Prevent computer from sleeping when display is of but on battery power? thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[‎Amphetamine](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12) is a free application that will give you a lot of power and flexibility about keeping your Mac awake under various conditions.

It has been around for a number of years and considered very trustworthy. I would recommend it without reservation.

‎Amphetamine even has an option to disable itself when the battery reaches a certain percentage, which will reduce the chance that you will unwittingly run the battery to 0% (it is not generally advisable to run the battery fully empty). Obviously, the final choice is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, depending on whether you want a temporary or permanent change in behavior:

1. Disable system sleep when on battery: `sudo pmset -b sleep 0`. This setting persists across reboots.
2. Run `caffeinate` in a Terminal window during periods of time when you don't want the system to sleep.

Comment: **Today I Learned:** `caffeinate` is not a third-party app. It's actually a built-in tool in macOS! Run `man caffeinate` to learn about it. (It's unclear if any Linux distros have this too.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that simply disabling `Turn display off after` and `Put hard disks to sleep when possible` under `System Preferences` > `Battery` > `Battery` has been sufficient for me to disable sleeping while on battery power.

Comment: I do not see these options